# Python MQTT on_subscribes fires an extra time

Tags: python, mqtt, mosquitto, paho

I am using loop_start and loop. I subscribe to 1 topic in the on_connection callback. However, the on_subscribe callback is fired 2 times. Then the second comes, the next loop() gets an error

```
loop: bad char in struct format
```

Here is the main section of the code, minus the callbacks (which are just print statements.

```
    self.client.connect(self.broker, self.port, 60)
    self.client.loop_start()

    self.client.on_connect = self.onConnect
    self.client.on_publish = self.onPublish
    self.client.on_subscribe = self.on_subscribe

 
  def run(self):
    while not self.client.is_connected():
      time.sleep(1)

    self.running = True
    while(self.running):
      row = self.db.getMessage()
      if(row != None):
        message = row[2]
        topic = 'data'
        timestamp = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime())
        try:
          ret = self.client.publish(topic, message, 0)
          pass
        except Exception as ex:
          print(str(ex))
      try:
        self.client.loop(0.1)
      except Exception as ex:
        print('loop:', str(ex))
```

Any suggestions as to how to prevent the subscribe callback and more importantly the bad char in struct format error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [the docs](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python?tab=readme-ov-file#loop_start--loop_stop) "Do not mix the different loop functions".

You are calling `self.client.loop_start()` which "runs a thread in the background to call loop() automatically"; you then call `self.client.loop(0.1)` within the loop in your code. This will lead to unpredictable results (`loop` is not designed to be run multiple times concurrently, so does not employ synchronization).

As the docs say "Using loop() on it's own is no longer recommended" I'd suggest replacing the `self.client.loop(0.1)` with a `time.sleep()` or equivalent.